# How to pass parameters with Inertia to Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm working on a small scale project, let's call it a playground for testing purposes.

I have some data:

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: this.$inertia.form({
        id: "",
        name: "",
        email: "",
        files: "",
      }),
     };
    }
```

A form handles the request through a function call on submit:

```
      this.form
        .transform((data) => ({
          ...data,
          name: this.sample.name,
          email: this.sample.email,
          files: this.sample.files,
        }))
        .patch(
          this.route("cms.products.sample.update", {
            sample: this.sample,
          }),
          {
            forceFormData: true,
            onSuccess: () => {
              this.form.reset();
            },
          }
        );
```

The sample object that is passed refers to the object that needs to be updated. He is passed correctly and Laravel's dd($sample); reads it properly.

The problem lies in the form data that it is passed. Data is not passed to the $request->all(), that is to the attributes of the request. Rather it is passed to the content part and it is parsed in a very weird way, like this:

```
#content: """
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryvh1XjftW9MtXqoUC
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"
    
    
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryvh1XjftW9MtXqoUC
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
    
    Sample Name
```

Without passing custom sample data the form data is correctly passed to the $request->all(), but then an error occurs requiring a model to be passed on update

Laravels Controller looks like this:

```
    public function update(UpdateSampleRequest $request, Sample $sample)
    {
        dd($request, $sample);
    }
```

Route is registered in web.php:

```
 PUT|PATCH admin/products/sample/{sample}.......... cms.products.sample.update › SampleController@update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that Laravel doesn't handle `PUT` requests with files. Once changed to `POST`, and a custom route handler was added everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you not modified route key or key name

you can change `this.route(` to `route(` and pass id like `this.sample.id`...

```
...
route("cms.products.sample.update", {
   sample: this.sample.id,
}),
...
```